# How to get comma separated values and use them in select statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column called RANDOM in T2 which has comma separated values lets say `age, gender, dob`. I want to get these three values of the id=1 and get these values from T1 id=1

I mean if value of RANDOM for id=1 in T2 is `age, gender, dob` then query would be:

`Select age, gender, dob from T1 where id=1`

but I am not able to figure out how to separate the three comma separated values and use them in a select query after that. By now, I could only understand:

`Select RANDOM from T2 where id = 1`

but can't figure out after that.

Comment: Which database are you using? Is it MySQL or SQLite3? Btw, storing items as comma separated lists is a really bad idea - it breaks database normalization and is a pain to work with as you might have noticed.

Comment: @calamari That question uses Postgresql not SQlite

Comment: That question also only deal with the situation when you know the total number of comma separated values.

Comment: @jpw I can't modify the database, I know it's bad practice but I can't change the table. Can you tell me a way to do it while keeping the comma separated values?

Comment: @calamari That question appears to be misleading as the answer is for MSSQL and not SQLite. I linked it too and just noticed.

Comment: @jpw, now I feel really silly, posting two invalid threads :-p

Comment: @KhawarAli I don't think you can do this inside SQLite without resorting to implementing your own functions in some supported language - it might be easier to handle it on the client side in a high-level programming language like Java or Python.

Comment: @KhawarAli, I concur with jpw...especially since you said that it's an unknown number of comma separated values.  Even if there were a way, you'd need to know how many so that you could select the values INTO a specific variable.  Since you don't know how many, you need to explode() or split() it into an array server-side or client-side with a language that can handle arrays.